# Show value in tag Label on c# under condition

Tags: c#, tags

In my tag Label with name **Item** on form in aspx page in c# I need show *disabled* value when the value of **Item** in database is **-1**.

I have tried this solution without success because in the Label the value is always -1.

Can you help me ?

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Item").Equals("-1") ? "disabled" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Item") %>
```

Comment: Please tag this question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling **DataBinder** instead of simply returning a **string**:

Change this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Item").Equals("-1") ? 
             "disabled" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Item") %>
```

To:

```
<%#(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Item").ToString() =="-1") ? 
             "disabled" : DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Item")%>
```

What you are doing is returning a string instead of executing the binding expression.